# Is there a better way of erasing dynamic array elements?

Tags: c++

For example, I have a dynamic array in C++, which is similar to an `std::vector`. When implementing an `erase` function, is this the best way forward, or is there a better way which is quicker / more efficient?

```
void erase(iterator it)
{
    my_array<template_argument> x;
    for(iterator i = begin(); i != end(); ++i)
    {
        if(i == it)
        {
            continue;
        }
        x.push(*i);
    }
    *this = x;
}
```

Comment: By "similar to std::vector", you mean that the memory must be contiguous, right?  Also, is "my_array" generic for any data type, or is it only used for some subset (e.g. built-in value types like int or double)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could perform in-place removal instead of making a new copy of almost the whole array.

```
for(iterator i = it; i+1 != end(); ++i)
{
    *i = *(i+1); // or std::iter_swap(i, i+1); if swapping is more efficient
}
pop();
```

Comment: And with C++11, `std::move` may be faster/required depending of `T`.

Comment: Note: there is a strong difference in terms of exception safety though. The OP's code implements **Strong Exception Guarantee** (aka transaction-mode): if any exception is thrown the original object is left untouched; your code only implements **Basic Exception Guarantee**: if any exception is thrown by a copy constructor, then you are left with a bunch of shifted elements, a half-copied one, etc... basically your whole array is trashed. Of course, Strong Exception Guarantee usually has a significant cost...

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your requirements. As mentioned, in general you would be using `std::iter_swap` to shift all elements before (or after) the element you wish to remove.

If you look at `std::deque`, for example, it guarantees that at most `N/2` elements are shifted by choosing whether to shift those before or after depending on whether the element to be deleted is closer to the head or the tail.